# Reading variables outside of the scope of node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I want to be able to read a variable from a node.js module after uploading a file through a POST function. For example

Server.js

```
app.post('upload')upload.single('filetoupload'), (req, res)=>{
var filename =req.file.filename
console.log(req, fileStorage, filename) 
res.status(204).end();
});
```

app.js

```
var filename;
function doSomething(){
//do something
console.log(filename)
}
```

is this something that can be done? I've tried to export and import but that doesnt seem to work with the scope that I'm in any suggestions? (I'm new to node so be nice)

Comment: Where is app.js run? In the browser?

Comment: yes, its a file that consists of functions that are called from an html file

Comment: If it's a file on the browser, you won't be able to read it from your node server. Can you explain a little more what you're trying to do?

Comment: Return the file name and data in the post endpoint? You cannot directly read variables in the backend from the frontend

Comment: @evolutionxbox could I possibly create a json form with the arguments i need and pull them from there via a ajax function with a post method?

Comment: What if multiple clients are uploading multiple files to your server? Which file name do you want to get where?

Comment: `app.post('upload')upload.single('filetoupload'), …` looks like a syntax error. Was that meant to be `app.post('upload', upload.single('filetoupload'), …`? If yes, please [edit] your question to fix it.